# Galaxy nexus Intent.ACTION_PICK bug on Jelly Bean (4.1.1)

Tags: android, gallery, android-4.2-jelly-bean, google-nexus

I've found a very frustrating bug on galaxy nexus. I start az `ACTION_PICK` activity to select image from, after starting it, the device shows the gallery, and immediately return and call `onActivityResult`, so I can't pick an image. It's only on *galaxy nexus* after update to Jelly Bean.

```
Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, RequestCodeCollection.GALLERY_IMAGE_SELECT);
```

I tested image picking with Instagram, and it worked well. What could be the trick?

**UPDATE**

I removed all code from `onActivityResult()` and I tried to remove overriding `onActivityResult()`. It not works. I checked how Instagram works. They use an `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` and a chooser. To create chooser is very important, because in this way user can't select a default source. If I don't create a chooser for every picking, I can select default source (like gallery, filemanager etc.), and after selecting the default the problem comes back.

```
Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent. ACTION_GET_CONTENT , android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media. EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
photoPickerIntent.setType( "image/*" );
startActivityForResult(Intent. createChooser(photoPickerIntent, "Select Picture"),RequestCodeCollection. GALLERY_IMAGE_SELECT);
```

---

I removed all code from onActivityResult() and I tried to remove overriding onActivityResult(). It not works. I checked how Instagram works. They use an ACTION_GET_CONTENT and a chooser. To create chooser is very important, because in this way user can't select a default source. If I don't create a chooser for every picking, I can select default source (like gallery, filemanager etc.), and after selecting the default the problem comes back.

```
Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent. ACTION_GET_CONTENT , android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media. EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
photoPickerIntent.setType( "image/*" );
startActivityForResult(Intent. createChooser(photoPickerIntent, "Select Picture"),RequestCodeCollection. GALLERY_IMAGE_SELECT);
```

Comment: R u starting activity for result from tabactivity?
As I found similar issue when I start activity for result from tabactivity on any version of Android.

Comment: Instead of sending image in result when you finish activity, save image bitmap in a static variable 
whatever you are doing processing after you get image put it in onResume() Also I think you need to maintain a flag.

Comment: Yeah, I know that issue, but it's a single activity, and only has problem on galaxy nexus 4.1.1. On HTC flyer, Sensation, Galaxy S3 works perfectly.

Comment: I see, but I can't even select an image. It shows gallery view only for ~1 second.

Comment: Remove all the code from onActivityResult() and then try again.