# when switching intents I lose data

Tags: android, android-intent

When switching intents I lose data from the previous onActivityResult I need it to keep both numbers it gets from the user, currently it will keep one number, then when the next is entered it loses the previous, here's code:

```
package com.eric.theworks;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

Button width, height, calc;
TextView area;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    width = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    height = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    calc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    area = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    width.setOnClickListener(this);
    height.setOnClickListener(this);
    calc.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent i = new Intent(this, Numbers.class);
    switch (v.getId()) {

    case R.id.button1:
        // width
        i.putExtra("numbers", "width");
        startActivityForResult(i, 1);

        break;

    case R.id.button2:
        // height
        i.putExtra("numbers", "height");
        startActivityForResult(i, 1);

        break;

    case R.id.button3:
        // calc

        break;

    }


    }

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (data.getExtras().containsKey("widthInfo")){
        width.setText(data.getStringExtra("widthInfo"));

}
    if (data.getExtras().containsKey("heightInfo")){
        height.setText(data.getStringExtra("heightInfo"));

}

}

}





package com.eric.theworks;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Numbers extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
EditText number;
Button sendInfo;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.numbers);
    number = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    sendInfo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    sendInfo.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String s = number.getText().toString();
    Intent i = getIntent();
    String msg = i.getStringExtra("numbers");
    if (msg.contentEquals("width")) {
        i.putExtra("widthInfo", s);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
        finish();

    }
    if (msg.contentEquals("height")) {
        i.putExtra("heightInfo", s);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
        finish();

    }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use static variable to store the previous data.
Declare static string globally.

```
static String widthInfo="";
static String heightInfo="";
```

Also Give different Requestcode.

```
case R.id.button1:
        // width
        i.putExtra("numbers", "width");
        startActivityForResult(i, 1);

        break;

    case R.id.button2:
        // height
        i.putExtra("numbers", "height");
        startActivityForResult(i, 2);
```

Then use it in your onActivityResult.

```
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
         switch (requestCode) {
        case (1): {

        if (data.getExtras().containsKey("widthInfo")){
            widthInfo=data.getStringExtra("widthInfo")
            width.setText(data.getStringExtra("widthInfo"));

    } else {
    height.setText(heightInfo);
    width.setText(widthInfo);
    }
        }
   break;
       case (2): 
        {
        if (data.getExtras().containsKey("heightInfo")){
            heightInfo=data.getStringExtra("heightInfo")
            height.setText(data.getStringExtra("heightInfo"));

    }else {
    height.setText(heightInfo);
    width.setText(widthInfo);
    }

    }
   break;
    }
}
```

Comment: This method does work, but for some reason it gets rid of the text on button 2 and makes it blank (tho can still be used), as of right now they but just say "button", but that would change eventually.

Comment: you can do one thing. put the resultCode different 1 for width and 2 for height let say then in activityResult separate above code according to resultCode. switch(ResultCode){case 1: {// code of width break;} case 2: { // code of height. break;}}

Comment: Same issue.... it is strange as Tutorial I watched guy coded it the original way and showed himself running it and everything and it worked fine.  Heres link: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=03uml_haPH0&list=SP667C75EE599C22C6

Comment: Ok very strange, the program works on a avd but not my actual device lol?

Comment: whats different in your edited version anyway maybe im missing somthing? I tryed the ="";

Comment: check else condition for both cases you will find the difference

Comment: and I declare the string with empty "".

Comment: Only works in the avd, on phone the other button goes back to saying "Button".

Comment: I dont get the meaning saying "Button".

Comment: I lose the height or the width, and it goes back to default.

Comment: ok but just try the new edition that i just put and than if it is not work i will look into other alternatives.

Comment: No, same result.... Since it works in avd would it prob work on most phones just not mine lol?

Comment: Phone is 4.1.1 verizon galaxy nexus. let me try using a emulated avd and see if it has same result.

Comment: Seems you cannot make a 4.1.1 avd?

Comment: you can also use shared preference as another alternative

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, but since this whole app is just for learning purposes I think I will just test it on the avd. Sorry to take up so much of your time.

Comment: its my pleasure .. we must always in a learning curve .. you can upvote answer if you find it useful.

Comment: Would if i had the rep sorry :( Maybe ill have it soon.

Comment: and try to use shared preference instead of static variable. if that work thats fine and if it is not work you will learn about shared preferences instead.

Comment: So I have found information, seems it is a bug with galaxy nexus and onActivityResult and getIntent:       http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14354081/galaxy-nexus-intent-action-pick-bug-on-jelly-bean-4-1-1

Answer (score 0):

you can use Bundle to pass data from one activity to another rather than the intent directly. for example:

```
 Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString("SingleClick",a );
        b.putString("LongClick", "no");
        i.putExtras(b);
```

and to get the data in another activity use

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        String admin = bundle.getString("LongClick");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = number.getText().toString();
Intent i = getIntent();
String msg = i.getStringExtra("numbers");
if (msg.contentEquals("width")) {
    i.putExtra("widthInfo", s);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
    finish();

}
```

make sure the string **s** has any values....

Comment: What do you mean? It gets text from the edit field in .Numbers. It does work and return the string but the issue is when I change heightInfo the the widthInfo just goes back to saying "button", where I need to keep both strings.